# Unable to remove directory, directory not empty

Tags: ftp, apache-http-server

The directory is in fact empty according to FTP, how can I delete this directory even though SmartFTP is throwing this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set full permissions on folder first, then try deleting it again:

```
CHMOD 777 <folder>
```

Also check it does not contain files with names that begin with ".", as these may appear hidden. 
Eg,

```
DELETE .htaccess
```

Answer (score 1):

Is someone else using that directory?

Answer (score 1):

FTP isn't a reliable way to check to see if a directory is empty or not. Do you have local access to the machine?

Answer (score 0):

Check first if you have a permission to rename it, if not then John is right that folder is not owned by you.

Answer (score 0):

This is usually caused by hidden files.

In SmartFTP:

> 1. Select **Favorites > Edit** Favorites from the SmartFTP menu. The
>      SmartFTP Favorites window appears.
> 2. From the SmartFTP Favorites window select the Favorite FTP login. Right
>      click on the Favorite and select
>      Properties. The Properties dialog
>      appears.
> 3. Under the FTP option select Transfer. From the Transfer tab under
>      Directory Listing Options enable the
>      options "[-a] Show All Files" & "[-L]
>      Resolve Links".

You can then check the folder again for hidden files. If this does not turn up anything, contact  your host, they will remove the folder for you.